# How to add multiple columns in current select statement as a new field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, pivot

I have the following query:

```
select

    sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'ACT Payment' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) AS [FTI-ACT Payment],
    sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'Bulk' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-Bulk],
    sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'Dedicated' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-DED],
    sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'FMS' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-FMS],
    sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION =  'Managed Service' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-MS],
    sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION not in ('ACT Payment','Bulk','Dedicated','FMS','Managed Service') AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-Other],
    sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION not in ('ACT Payment','Corrected') and c.Balance>0 AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-DR],
    sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION not in ('ACT Payment','Cancelling') and c.Balance < 0 AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-CR],
    sum(case when c.VOUCHER like 'ARP%' and c.LedgerJournalACType = 'Bank' and c.TransType2 = 'Payment' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [New Payments]
    
    
    

from [AX2cTest].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] c
```

with this output:

```
 FTI-ACT Payment    FTI-Bulk    FTI-DED     FTI-FMS    FTI-MS   FTI-Other   FTI-DR      FTI-CR  New Payments
    -122995.14      114521.67   728830.9    2793.46    53137.07 3000       902352.58    -69.48  0
```

I need to add a balance field that simply adds all of these fields. This is just a sample of a rather long query though. I'm trying to avoid adding each lengthy statement into a (col1 + col2) format, This would seem to slow down a query and this will be querying a production environment soon. Is this my only option?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is a subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    [FTI-ACT Payment] + [FTI-Bulk] + [FTI-DED] + [FTI-FMS] + [FTI-MS] + [FTI-Other] + [FTI-DR] + [FTI-CR] + [New Payments] AS total
from (
    select
        sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'ACT Payment' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) AS [FTI-ACT Payment],
        sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'Bulk' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-Bulk],
        sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'Dedicated' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-DED],
        sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'FMS' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-FMS],
        sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION =  'Managed Service' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-MS],
        sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION not in ('ACT Payment','Bulk','Dedicated','FMS','Managed Service') AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-Other],
        sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION not in ('ACT Payment','Corrected') and c.Balance>0 AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-DR],
        sum(case when c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION not in ('ACT Payment','Cancelling') and c.Balance < 0 AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-CR],
        sum(case when c.VOUCHER like 'ARP%' and c.LedgerJournalACType = 'Bank' and c.TransType2 = 'Payment' THEN convert(float,c.Balance) ELSE 0 END) As [New Payments]
    from [AX2cTest].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] c
) t
```

As the question and query stand, there is not way you can avoid enumerating the columns you want to `sum()`.

It *might* be possible, however, to build an additional `sum()` expression that brings together with `or` all individual conditions in the existing `sum()`s. This would look like:

```
sum(case 
    when 
        (c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'ACT Payment' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer')
        or (c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'Bulk' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer')
        or (c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'Dedicated' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer')
        or (c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'FMS' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer')
        or (c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION =  'Managed Service' AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer')
        or (c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION not in ('ACT Payment','Bulk','Dedicated','FMS','Managed Service') AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer')
        or (c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION not in ('ACT Payment','Corrected') and c.Balance > 0 AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer')
        or (c.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION not in ('ACT Payment','Cancelling') and c.Balance < 0 AND c.TransType2 = 'Customer')
        or ( c.VOUCHER like 'ARP%' and c.LedgerJournalACType = 'Bank' and c.TransType2 = 'Payment')
    then convert(float,c.Balance) 
    else 0 
end) as total
```

We could work and try to shorten this by factorizing some of the conditions. Depending on your actual data, neater options may be available to shorten the conditions.